# Clustering, does sorting data before injestion improve performance of truncating my table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My goal is to ingest data, sorted on a specific column so that the partitions are also in that order, to make pruning on that column efficient.

I would like to minimize the cost of sorting, and would like some guidance on how often I should recluster.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE test_order(n NUMBER, s STRING);
INSERT INTO test_order 
VALUES 
   (12, 'a'), 
   (11, 'b'), 
   (10, 'c'), 
   (9, 'd'), 
   (8, 'e'), 
   (7, 'f'), 
   (6, 'g'), 
   (5, 'h'), 
   (6, 'i'), 
   (5, 'j'), 
   (4, 'k'), 
   (3, 'l'), 
   (2, 'm'), 
   (1, 'n');

SELECT * FROM test_order 
ORDER BY n ASC;

ALTER TABLE test_order CLUSTER BY (n, s);
ALTER TABLE test_order RECLUSTER;

SELECT n, s FROM test_order;
SELECT SYSTEM$CLUSTERING_INFORMATION('test_order', '(n,s)');
```

> This was the information on the first insert:

```html
{
  "cluster_by_keys" : "LINEAR(N, S)",
  "total_partition_count" : 1,
  "total_constant_partition_count" : 0,
  "average_overlaps" : 0.0,
  "average_depth" : 1.0,
  "partition_depth_histogram" : {
    "00000" : 0,
    "00001" : 1,
    "00002" : 0,
    "00003" : 0,
    "00004" : 0,
    "00005" : 0,
    "00006" : 0,
    "00007" : 0,
    "00008" : 0,
    "00009" : 0,
    "00010" : 0,
    "00011" : 0,
    "00012" : 0,
    "00013" : 0,
    "00014" : 0,
    "00015" : 0,
    "00016" : 0
  }
}
```

> This was the information on the second insert:

```
INSERT INTO test_order 
VALUES 
   (12, 'p'), 
   (11, 'f'), 
   (10, 'z'), 
   (9, 'y'), 
   (8, 'x'), 
   (7, 'w'), 
   (6, 'v'), 
   (5, 'u'), 
   (6, 't'), 
   (5, 's'), 
   (4, 'r'), 
   (3, 'q'), 
   (2, 'p'), 
   (1, 'o');
```

```html
{
  "cluster_by_keys" : "LINEAR(N, S)",
  "total_partition_count" : 2,
  "total_constant_partition_count" : 0,
  "average_overlaps" : 1.0,
  "average_depth" : 2.0,
  "partition_depth_histogram" : {
    "00000" : 0,
    "00001" : 0,
    "00002" : 2,
    "00003" : 0,
    "00004" : 0,
    "00005" : 0,
    "00006" : 0,
    "00007" : 0,
    "00008" : 0,
    "00009" : 0,
    "00010" : 0,
    "00011" : 0,
    "00012" : 0,
    "00013" : 0,
    "00014" : 0,
    "00015" : 0,
    "00016" : 0
  }
}
```

Then after a second recluster:

```html
{
  "cluster_by_keys" : "LINEAR(N, S)",
  "total_partition_count" : 2,
  "total_constant_partition_count" : 0,
  "average_overlaps" : 1.0,
  "average_depth" : 2.0,
  "partition_depth_histogram" : {
    "00000" : 0,
    "00001" : 0,
    "00002" : 2,
    "00003" : 0,
    "00004" : 0,
    "00005" : 0,
    "00006" : 0,
    "00007" : 0,
    "00008" : 0,
    "00009" : 0,
    "00010" : 0,
    "00011" : 0,
    "00012" : 0,
    "00013" : 0,
    "00014" : 0,
    "00015" : 0,
    "00016" : 0
  }
}
```

Sorry, I am new to formatting, but after inserting into a particular order, there was not much change to the clustering ratios - is this because my dataset example is too small, or that the order does not matter for cluster performance?

Comment: Why are you asking about improving truncation?  I'm a little confused about the title.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking here. Truncation is a metadata operation so sorting the table as you load it won't impact the performance of a truncate. It will help however with the clustering of the table. Also manually reclustering a table will be deprecated in newer versions of Snowflake I wouldn't rely on that.

Comment: SimonD, thank you, what I was exploring was if I pre-loaded the data in a particular order I thought it might help with finding data quicker, I am moving from a model where a window is required, and realizing now that Snowflake does this all for you. What I really should be asking is how often I should be clustering my data, as auto-clustering will cluster everytime we ingest new data.  Truncation was going to be scheduled every month and I had a theory that if the clusters  we organized by the windows we wanted truncate it would save compute time. Still learning, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you going to ingest the data sorted, I'm don't think you need to cluster the table.  Your data will be naturally clustered and you will get the desired pruning.

Comment: This is only the case if you only insert into the table once and never touch it again I think.